# how to multiply columns of one file by the number in same row of another file?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have two files both with same number of rows.
File1 has 16 columns and file2 has 2 column

file1

```
1 2 3 4...
2 3 4 5...
3 4 5 6...
```

file2

```
text 10
text 11
text 12
```

Now I want another file with following output

```
10 20 30 40...
22 33 44 55...
36 48 60 72...
```

I tried using awk but was not successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
$ awk '{ getline line <"file2"; split(line,a); for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i *= a[2] };1' file1
10 20 30 40
22 33 44 55
36 48 60 72
```

For each line in `file1`, which is given on the command line, this `awk` program reads a line from `file2` and splits it on the whitespace into the array `a`.  The second element of `a` is used to multiply each field in the current record (from `file1`).  At the end of the cycle, the trailing `1` causes the modified record to be outputted.

If the text in `file2` contains whitespace, and if it's always *the last* field in that file that should be used, then keep track of how many fields the `line` string is split into:

```bash
$ awk '{ getline line <"file2"; nf=split(line,a); for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i *= a[nf] };1' file1
10 20 30 40
22 33 44 55
36 48 60 72
```

To additionally avoid hard-coding the name of the second file, pass its name into an `awk` variable on the command line:

```bash
$ awk -v other=file2 '{ getline line <other; nf=split(line,a); for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i *= a[nf] };1' file1
10 20 30 40
22 33 44 55
36 48 60 72
```

... or pass its name in an environment variable:

```bash
$ other=file2 awk '{ getline line <ENVIRON["other"]; nf=split(line,a); for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i *= a[nf] };1' file1
10 20 30 40
22 33 44 55
36 48 60 72
```